# Computing a random subset in Python - what's wrong in my code?

Tags: python, random, hash, hashtable

This code is to return a subset with size k from the set size n (EPI 5.15). That is, take n > 0, k <= n, and from n we (hypothetically) form a set {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1} from which we pick k elements to form a subset. There are nCk possibilities of picking a subset and we want it to be uniformly picked and we also want the permutation in that subset is also random. There are three versions of codes -- from official solution, my tweak, and my own solution. The latter two are WRONG but I don't know why. I will explain the gist of the algorithm right below the three codes.

##### Official Solution

```
def random_subset(n: int, k: int) -> List[int]:
    H = {}
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        rmap = H.get(r, r)
        imap = H.get(i, i)
        H[r] = imap
        H[i] = rmap
    return [H[i] for i in range(k)]
```

##### Change to the official solution (WRONG)

```
def random_subset(n: int, k: int) -> List[int]:
    H = {}
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        H[r] = H.get(i, i)
        H[i] = H.get(r, r)
    return [H[i] for i in range(k)]
```

##### My solution (DEAD WRONG)

```
def random_subset(n: int, k: int) -> List[int]:
    H = {}
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        if r in H:
            H[i], H[r] = H[r], i
        else:
            H[i], H[r] = r, i
    return [H[i] for i in range(k)]
```

##### Underlying Logic

We pick an element from the part of array A, <0, 1, 2, ..., n-1>, without duplicate. At first, pick r from array A and swap it with A[0]; then pick another r and swap it with A[1] ... until we have filled A[k-1], in total we have k elements, like the following code:

```
'''
A = <0, 1, 2, ..., n-1>
i    0  1  2       n-1
'''

def random_sampling(k, A):
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, len(A))
        A[i], A[r] = A[r], A[i]

A = [i for i in range(n)]
k = some_constant
random_sampling(k, A)
answer = A[:k]
```

To reduce space complexity from O(n) to O(k) by mimicking an array <0, 1, 2, ..., n-1>, we changed the right above code into an official solution that uses a hash table from which we select an element to be included in a subset. The problem arises in the way I use hash table differently from original answer but I don't know why.

Comment: Where does this problem and its solution come from?  Who is the "official" that declared your solutions wrong, and why?  I don't think the official algorithm actually implements the description in your "Underlying logic" section.  I see no array "A" nor elements being swapped as you describe.

Comment: Can I assume this is for the sake of an exercise, and that's why you don't just use `random.sample`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, this is for the sake of an exercise.

Comment: @PaulCornelius This is an exercise 5.15 from EPI (Elements of Programming Interviews in Python). The official solution is in https://github.com/adnanaziz/EPIJudge/tree/master/epi_judge_python_solutions/random_subset.py. If I run with the second and third code, it says the subset is not randomly generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

, the last one seems not to make basic sense. An assignment like

```
            H[i] = H[r], i
```

binds `H[i]` to a 2-tuple, not to an integer.

The middle (second) one is stepping on its own toes:

```
        H[r] = H.get(i, i)
        H[i] = H.get(r, r)
```

The `get()` in the second line is more-than-less useless, because `H[r]` was bound in the line right above. `r` is *always* in `H` when the second line executes, so that pair of lines is the same as, e.g.,

```
        temp = H.get(i, i)
        H[i] = H[r] = temp
```

Which is pretty clearly not what you intended to do.

By the way, if you're keen to reduce the line count for some reason, this should work:

```
    H = {}
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        H[i], H[r] = H.get(r, r), H.get(i, i)
    return [H[i] for i in range(k)]
```

But I find the first version to be clearest.

### Edit: new version of last code

The last version was changed to do:

```
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        if r in H:
            H[i], H[r] = H[r], i
        else:
            H[i], H[r] = r, i
```

Now that *would* implement the conceptual "swap" logic *if* it were always the case, at the top of the loop. that `H.get(i, i) == i`. But that isn't the case, so it can fail.

For example, start with `n=9` and `k=5` (this isn't delicate - pretty much arbitrary). On the first loop iteration (`i=0`), suppose `r=1` is picked. Then `H[0]` is set to 1 and `H[1]` to 0. That's fine. *But*, now it's not the case that `H.get(1, 1)` is 1 - it's 0. That can cause trouble on the next step.

On the next iteration (`i=1`), suppose `r=5` is picked. So the code does

```
            H[i], H[r] = r, i # which is
            H[1], H[5] = 5, 1
```

Oops! Now 0 (which was in `H[1]`) is no longer in `H`, and 1 is in H twice (it was in `H[0]`, and now it's also in `H[5]`). That's not "a swap" at all.

BTW, there's another way to write this I like better, because it makes it very explicit that once a subset element is picked, that decision will never be changed. It also cuts the size of `H`:

```
def random_subset(n, k):
    H = {}
    result = []
    for i in range(k):
        r = random.randrange(i, n)
        result.append(H.get(r, r))
        H[r] = H.pop(i, i)
    return result
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry, there was a typo. I feel sorry for you, the earth, and heaven for misleading your valuable time into the wrong code. I modified a code, adding H[r] for the second assignment.

Comment: But it doesn't look like you changed the middle version, and that's still wrong for reasons already explained.

Comment: That's right, only third code had the typo and second remains the same. Huge thanks for your teaching. I will learn from your valuable comment now. I should learn hard the bindings again. This has been confounding for me. Wow, it's a true honor to receive a comment from 'the' Tim Peters!

Comment: Would it be a good starting point to read your "Python Cookbook" to have a good foundation of the concepts of Python?

Comment: I edited a chapter of an older edition of the Cookbook, and that's it. I liked that book, but haven't even seen more recent editions. Looks to me like you're doing fine already, though! Trying things, and thinking about happens when you make changes, is a very effective (if frustrating at times) way to _really_ learn things.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep your words in mind and keep going. Today is a True blessing day. :)

Comment: See edit at bottom for a discussion of what goes wrong in the newer version of the middle code.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Well, what I did edit was the third code to H[i], H[r] = H[r], i. But as it was my bad, so this answer was fair. So I will thankfully mark your answer to be correct. Huge thanks, legend! :)

Comment: My mistake! I meant the third version, not the middle one. The edit I added is indeed about the new `H[i], H[r] = H[r], i` code.

Comment: OMG, there was a thorough updated answer, huge thanks! By the time you wrote the last comment  (begins with 'See edit~') somehow I wasn't able to see your new edit and there must've been my browser issue or possible Stackoverflow's update lag. Now I can see your answer and now I could learn a TON! This discourse turns out to teach me in a multifaceted way -- not only about the programming itself but also about life: like the generosity, kindness, and humility that you've shown to me. I talked about this discourse with my friend and they were greatly moved too. Thank you so ** googol much! :)